# Signals extraction from different multivariate normal - with a prior and 2 biased signals (each with different precision)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, signal-processing

I have a problem with signal extraction. I've been checking other posts (and multiple documents) considering similar but simpler problems. Putting everything together, I think I was able to derive the solution, but I'm unsure and looking for someone to kindly confirm to me that what I did is correct.

Suppose that I'm interested in $\theta\sim N(\mu_{\theta},\sigma^2_{\theta})$, but I only observe two imperfect (biased) signals
\begin{eqnarray}
s=&\theta+\epsilon\\
g=&\theta+y
\end{eqnarray}
where $\epsilon\sim N(\mu_{\epsilon},\sigma^2_{\epsilon})$ and $y\sim N(\mu_{y},\sigma^2_{y})$ (with $\theta$, $\epsilon$ and $y$ being independent).

What I need to compute is basically $  E(\theta\mid s,g)$. I came to the conclusion that I can obtain a sufficient statistic by averaging signals $s,g$ using weights $\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{\left(\sigma_{y}^{2}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}\right) }$ and $\frac{\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left(\sigma_{y}^{2}+\sigma_{\epsilon }^{2}\right)}$.

Then, denoting by $Z=\frac{\sigma
_{y}^{2}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) } s+\frac{\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left(
\sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}\right) }  g=\theta+\frac{\sigma
_{y}^{2}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) } \epsilon+\frac{\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left(
\sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}\right) } y$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
Z\mid \theta \sim N\left(\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2} \mu_{\epsilon}+\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2} \mu_{y}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) },\frac{\sigma
_{y}^{2}\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) }\right) \\
Z \sim N\left(\mu_{\theta}+\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2} \mu_{\epsilon}+\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2} \mu_{y}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) },\sigma^2_\theta+\frac{\sigma
_{y}^{2}\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) }\right)\\
cov(\theta,Z)=\sigma^2_{\theta}\\
E(\theta\mid Z)=     \mu_{\theta}+\frac{cov(\theta,Z)}{var(Z)}(Z-E(Z)) 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Replacing in $E(\theta\mid Z)$ I obtained:
\begin{equation}
    E(\theta\mid s,g)=  \mu_{\theta}+\frac{\sigma^2_{\theta}}{\sigma^2_\theta+\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}\sigma_{\epsilon }^{2}}{\left( \sigma_{y}^{2}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}\right) }}\left(Z-\left(\mu_{\theta}+\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2} \mu_{\epsilon}+\sigma _{\epsilon }^{2} \mu_{y}}{\left( \sigma _{y}^{2}+\sigma _{\epsilon
}^{2}\right) }\right)\right)
\end{equation}
which, after some algebra, becomes
\begin{equation}
    E(\theta\mid s,g)=E(\theta\mid Z)= \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}\sigma_{\epsilon }^{2}\mu_{\theta}+\sigma^2_{\theta}\sigma_{y}^{2}\left(s-\mu_{\epsilon}\right)
    +\sigma^2_{\theta}\sigma_{\epsilon }^{2}\left( g-\mu_{y}\right)
    }
    {
    \sigma^2_\theta \left( \sigma_{y}^{2}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}\right)+\sigma_{y}^{2}\sigma_{\epsilon }^{2}}
\end{equation}

I'd really appreciate it if you can double-check and confirm that what I did is correct.

Thanks!

PS: a couple of posts deal with similar issues, yet not the same. In particular, I think that my results are fully consistent with  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179213/mean-of-two-normal-distributions and [A priori normal and likelihood normal with different variances.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013809/a-priori-normal-and-likelihood-normal-with-different-variances?rq=1)